# class not found exception while running my camera with face detection project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I get a *class not found* exception. I think this error comes when there is a library issue. I am implementing face detection in my camera for that i used latest google play services library and appcompact v7 library. This project runs perfectly in android studio but in eclipse it shows a *class not found* exception.

following is the logcat errors

> 01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724): Process: com.example.customcamera, PID: 8724
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.customcamera/com.example.customcamera.SwipeCamera.MainView}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.customcamera.SwipeCamera.MainView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.customcamera-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.customcamera-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.customcamera.SwipeCamera.MainView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.customcamera-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.customcamera-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     ... 10 more
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.customcamera.SwipeCamera.MainView
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         ... 14 more
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.customcamera.SwipeCamera.MainView
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):         ... 13 more
>   01-27 08:03:46.499: E/AndroidRuntime(8724):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

In eclipse I am adding [these libraries and jars appcampact v7 library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNDyu.jpg),  and [google play services lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4isfQ.jpg) for face detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassNotFound means your classpath is wrong, which could be any number of reasons.  The fact that it works in one IDE and not the other just means that 1) you set up something differently in one over the other or 2) the build tools you're using acted differently in each.

For example, I've seen Eclipse projects ignore the Maven pom.xml file and just use libraries loaded into the project, or Android Studio might have some default libraries that Eclipse doesn't (or vice-versa).

ClassNotFound can also result when different version of a library uses different packages, if the new version did some major restructuring.

It can also be due to class loader problems.  So in a nutshell, tough to help without more details about how you're setting things up, how you're running, etc.